# Replace select dropdown with radio button with functionality

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, form-parameter, select-options

I have a dropdown with `male` and `female` options.
I am replacing it with radio buttons, I wrote the HTML, but for the HTML form to work where should I place `name` attribute on radio button

HTML for dropdown

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" title="Gender">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Male</option>
   <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

HTML for radio

```
<input type="radio" title="Gender" value="1"> Male
<input type="radio" title="Gender" value="2" checked="checked"> Female
```

For select, the `name` attribute will work when we submit the form, as it will send the select option as name parameter.
But where should I put `name` attribute for radio buttons?
If I put name attribute for both attribute same, it won't work
as two radio button cannot have the same `name`.

As I don't want to change the backend code, I want to work as before as it is for the select option, which used to send selected option through name attribute,

How to do the same for radio buttons. So that when any radio buttons are selected it sends the selected element in `name` parameters which doesn't require a change in backend code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can post unique values like this (to the same `$_POST` variable), HTML:

```
<input type="radio" title="gender" name="gender" value="1">Male
<input type="radio" title="gender" name="gender" value="2">Female
```

Access them in PHP with:

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
```

If you have a situation where you can select more than one radio button you can use an array, HTML:

```
<formgroup>
    <input type="radio" title="gender" name="something[0]" value="1">
    <input type="radio" title="gender" name="something[0]" value="2">
</formgroup>
<formgroup>
    <input type="radio" title="gender" name="something[1]" value="1">
    <input type="radio" title="gender" name="something[1]" value="2">
</formgroup>
```

Then in PHP you can access these values using:

```
$radio1 = $_POST['something'][0];
$radio2 = $_POST['something'][1];
```